# How disable Chromium inbound permissions request when initialize RTCPeerConnection

Tags: javascript, webrtc, chromium, jxbrowser

When I initialize RTCPeerConnection, `new RTCPeerConnection(...);`, I'm receiving the following popup

[image]

It's adding inbound rule in Windows FW,
I don't need it, event if I don't allow all my flows work well

I'm looking for a way to avoid this popup (set inbound network blocked by default)
I tried check for Chromium flags and RTCPeerConnection constructor options with no luck

Is there a way to avoid this popup?

I tried use chromium 75 and 84, same behavior

It's not happening in chromium 74

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you control chromium features, disable `enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns` will resolve it, but the real local IP addresses will be shown in WebRTC ICE candidates.

These firewall rules are typically added during installation.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1000955
has some information.